# Connect with curl to FTPS server and download file

Tags: curl, certificates, ftps

I'm able to connect to my FTPS server with TLS1.2 by `curl`, using `--cert`, `--key` and `--cacert` files. The command looks like:

```
curl -3 -k -v --ftp-ssl --tlsv1.2 --ftp-ssl-reqd --ftp-pasv --verbose \
                                --ssl                                 \
                                --cert ./cert.pem                     \
                                --cert-type PEM                       \
                                --key ./cert.key                      \
                                --key-type PEM                        \
                                --cacert ./cacert                     \
                                ftp://user:pass@10.10.100.1/file.txt
```

I see the contents of `file.txt` appear in the output of the command but I don't actually see the file being saved anywhere. Am I missing another argument in my curl command? I have not been able to find it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding option [`-O` / `--remote-name`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-O) to your command saves the output to the same filename as the remote filename
in your current working directory.

Add [`--output-dir <dir>`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--output-dir) to specify a target directory. This option is relatively new and was added in version 7.73.0.

Answer (score 1):

From `curl --help`:

> -o, --output  Write to file instead of stdout

So add an `-o file.txt` or `--output file.txt` to your command